# Merge the [outer] and [outer-join] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

To quote the tag wikis:

The wiki excerpt for [outer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outer) states that:

> An *Outer join* does not require each record in the two joined tables to have a matching record. The joined table retains each record—even if no other matching record exists.

The wiki excerpt for [outer-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outer-join), on the other hand, states that:

> An **outer join** defines a relationship between two tables where all records from one or both tables are returned regardless of the existence of a matching key-field in the other table. A full outer join combines the results of both tables. A left or right join returns all the records from the first or second specified table, respectively. NULLS are filled in for matches on either side. A self-join compares a table to a copy of itself.

They clearly refer to the same thing, although [outer-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outer-join) seems to do a better job of explaining it, IMHO.

Do we really need two tags here? Can they please be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I totally agree with this, it is confusing to have two tags that are referencing the same sql join.  I made [outer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outer) a synonym of [outer-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outer-join).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't have the rep on either tag to suggest it.